# Can a writer keep an editor's edits despite order cancellation?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, derivative-work

I wrote an article and hired a freelance editor who delivered a result that didn't match the value of how much I paid him. He agreed to refund me.

There are certain edits of his that I would like to use, but would that would infringe upon his rights since the order was cancelled?

Comment: If the editor returned the money not due to a contractual obligation, but just because you were dissatisfied, then why don’t you give the editor back some of the money since you like some of the work?

Comment: The editor refused my offer of partial payment.